# ActiveStorage with GCS files don't upload (Signature was not base64 encoded) || (SignatureDoesNotMatch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm building a Rails app that uses ActiveStorage and I'm having trouble going from S3 to Google.

Until now I was using S3 as my cloud storage and everything worked fine. But I want to use Google Storage because I plan to use a Google API to interact with files uploaded to a bucket there.

I'm still doing all this in the development environment.

- I changed `config/storage.yml` to add the relevant information

```
google_dev:
  service: GCS
  project: [REDACTED]
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("config/secrets/[MY_FILE].json") %>
  bucket: [REDACTED]
```

and changed `config/environments/development.rb` to `config.active_storage.service = :google_dev`

I also did a `rails db:reset` to start with a clean db.

But every time I try to upload a file I get the same error:

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for ::1 at 2019-09-25 02:54:43 +0200
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"blob"=>{"filename"=>"audioprueba03.wav", "content_type"=>"audio/wav", "byte_size"=>7080908, "checksum"=>"8WjGtwdMQH+YA/m3PkPqjw=="}, "direct_upload"=>{"blob"=>{"filename"=>"audioprueba03.wav", "content_type"=>"audio/wav", "byte_size"=>7080908, "checksum"=>"8WjGtwdMQH+YA/m3PkPqjw=="}}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["key", "0nklcvjevlgcetnz178djjhmb5hh"], ["filename", "audioprueba03.wav"], ["content_type", "audio/wav"], ["byte_size", 7080908], ["checksum", "8WjGtwdMQH+YA/m3PkPqjw=="], ["created_at", "2019-09-25 00:54:43.950138"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
  GCS Storage (1.8ms) Generated URL for file at key: 0nklcvjevlgcetnz178djjhmb5hh (https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/0nklcvjevlgcetnz178djjhmb5hh?GoogleAccessId=[REDACTED].iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1569373183&Signature=LKnSO1T3G4iF%2BOEw7fbS4%2FMZS7ne%2FiKqobJ5xb3iCsyONbCzNcp8X9PDcdiNKBMZUU4Pg9DyV5D%2Bq7YdEOG4GPvjokxH0GsWG9%2FbKBVYhHBYsGqWszqeDCzATMXUGcSMqnefHDZXu%2FTIwBKsS4HbRKcHfyQZwCy%2FKsFkTxR1huliSw36C650whKC3hunMD0tSwBr%2Fpi7JNIvAuGia3OwJVr9Da1PstfTebgLrMqlAdM1JxuzqRW5ZztIv6RArdJO3047MekyD5YNajI%2FWqsSfQLHsmkRiBe4G4Vy8yz%2Fhs%2B%2BmWpOTjvRYvYlMl8x8V3pazwiC%2F8qdB591MrCSiTBUQ%3D%3D)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms | Allocations: 4962)
```

If I follow the provided URL with a browser I get this:

```
<Error>
<Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code>
<Message>Your request has a malformed header.</Message>
<ParameterName>signature</ParameterName>
<Details>Signature was not base64 encoded</Details>
</Error>
```

If I curl the URL, what I get is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
```

I've tried it with the JSON provided by Google saved in `config/secrets/filename.json` and called as shown above.

Also providing the credentials info to the `credentials.yml.enc` (with the proper `rails credentials:edit`, of course.

Also setting my environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the JSON. All to no avail (I always get the same error).

I even did set CORS in my bucket to accept basically anything:

`[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],"method": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]`

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured it out.

The problem was with CORS in GCS.

After trying sooooooooo many configurations, it works if I update the GCS bucket CORS with the following:
```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Content-Md5"],
    "method": ["PUT", "GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: I have the same problem, however setting the CORS to the value provided by you doesn't work either :/